# AJAX Control Toolkit Assembly loading error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I encounter a problem...error is ....Ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll is in bin folder, but still I get this follwoing error...

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

My code is (in .aspx file):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="act"
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ASP.NET AJAX Extensions installed on your machine?